# Org Chart work locally and didn't work in deploy: jQuery(...).orgchart is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular7, orgchart

I'm working on organizational chart with angular library named orgchart.
The code source work locally on my machine and when we deploy the code on nginx server we got this error linked to jQuery.

This is my code :

```
>  organigramme.forEach((collab, i) => {
>      jQuery('#chart-container').append(jQuery('<div id="chart_'+i+'"></div>')); 
>      const chart = jQuery('#chart_'+i).orgchart({
>       'data' : collab,
>       'nodeContent': 'post',
```

[Console error on deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHxuk.png)

Github link : https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart.

Deployment server : nginx.

Otherwise, same work environment :
Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node: 10.16.3
npm : 6.7.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you load / include Orgchart to your project?

Comment: I just installed `"orgchart": "^2.1.9",` and add `"node_modules/orgchart/dist/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css",` && ` "node_modules/orgchart/dist/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js",` in angular.json

Comment: npm, link, ...?

Comment: Sorry i update my comment, you can see it again

Comment: Hmm... ok.
maybe it would be better to use the ES6 Version instead of jQuery.
So you can directly import it in your component and use it in your template. Without the need of jquery.
Or is it not a full angular app and you need the jquery-version?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't get for the first part, Can you simplify things for me with exemple? Otherwise, the app is angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small Angular wrapper on my [github: brandt-codes/orgchart-angular](https://github.com/brandt-codes/orgchart-angular).
Feel free to use ;-)
Will update and beatify this small project in the next days.

---

The minimal part:
TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import OrgChart from 'orgchart.js/src/orgchart.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orgchart',
  templateUrl: './orgchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orgchart.component.scss']
})
export class OrgchartComponent implements OnInit {
  private datascource = {
    'name': 'Lao Lao',
    'title': 'general manager',
    'children': [
      { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
      { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [
          { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
          { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
            'children': [
              { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
              { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' },
      { 'name': 'Yu Li', 'title': 'department manager' },
      { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
      { 'name': 'Yu Wei', 'title': 'department manager' },
      { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
      { 'name': 'Yu Tie', 'title': 'department manager' }
    ]
  };

  public orgchartFromData: OrgChart;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.orgchartFromData = new OrgChart({
      'chartContainer': '#chartContainerData',
      'data' : this.datascource,
      'depth': 2,
      'nodeContent': 'title'
    });
  }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="chartContainerData"></div>
```

PS: I used the `orgchart.js` package (not the `orgchart`).